# Destroying thread attributes from a different thread

Tags: pthreads

My question is if its possible to delete the attributes of a thread with a different thread. Like using the pthread_attr_destroy() method inside of a function of a thread to destroy the attributes of another thread and then it deletes it.

P.S thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have some kind of misunderstanding. The `pthread_attr_destroy` function destroys an attributes object itself (`pthread_attr_t`), not the attributes of a thread. Attributes objects are used to specify the attributes of a thread when a thread is created, but once a thread has certain attributes, those are attributes of the thread, not an attributes object.

Comment: Maybe i did not set up my question very clear.I have this program making two threads and each one has two different attributes. 

void *FirstThread(void *arg){

}

void *SecondThread(void *arg){

}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int rc;
pthead_t thread1,thread2;
pthread_attr_t &attr1,&attr2;
pthread_attr_init(&pta1);
pthread_attr_init(&pta2);
pthread_create(&thread1,&attr1,FirstThread,NULL);
pthread_create(&thread2,&attr2,SecondThread,NULL);
}
Is there a way to destroy attr1 from the SecondThread?

Comment: Yes, call `pthread_attr_destroy`. You can call these functions from any thread, it doesn't matter. But why wouldn't you just call `pthread_attr_destroy` immediately after calling `pthread_create`?

Comment: the project i am about to do is going to have some "malevolent" threads that find one random thread and destroy its attributes

Comment: Please read my answer again. That makes no sense. You can't destroy a thread's attributes. The `pthread_attr_destroy` function doesn't destroy a thread's attributes, it destroys an attributes object that could be used to set a thread's attributes when it's created.

Comment: Yea I know my bad i have made a huge misunderstanding there xD..Anyway can I destroy the first thread attribute's object inside the second thread by using the command...pthread_attr_destroy(&attr1)...?

Comment: Yes, but it's not "the first thread attribute's object". Attribute objects don't belong to threads, they belong to the process as a whole. Any thread can destroy an attributes object by calling `pthread_attr_destroy` on it. That will have no effect on any existing threads but it will prevent the attributes object from being used to give attributes to newly-created threads.

Comment: When I compile it it says that the attr object is undeclared

Comment: I have declared the objects of attr1,attr2 outside the main() meaning thats it is global right?And then inside the SecondThread I have pthread_attr_destroy(&attr1]);

Comment: void *Malevolent(void *threadid) //<---Malevolent
{
   long tid;
   tid = (long)threadid;
   printf("I am the #%ld! thread and I am malevolent\n", tid);
   pthread_attr_destroy(&attr[tid+1]);
   pthread_exit(NULL);

Comment: pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];
   pthread_attr_t  attr[NUM_THREADS];
   long t;
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) //<--- main
{    printf("In main: creating thread %ld,%d\n", t);
     rc=pthread_attr_init(&pta[t]);
     rc = pthread_create(&threads[t],&attr[t], Malevolent, (void *)t);

Comment: If I erase the pthread_attr_destroy line the code works fine... :(

Comment: Okay. Is the definition of `pta` prior to the `pthread_attr_destroy` call?

Comment: I just declared pthread_t and pthread_attr_t at the top of the code and not after main() and it compiled....I might as well die in a hole... xD

P.S thank you soooooo much I really appreciate all your help towards me :)